# Trouble with simple(?) jquery/javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

So I am having a problem with something that I think should be very simple.

I coded this example for simplicity's sake: I first noticed the problem in a larger body of code.  However the issue still persists here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#test
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<script src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>
</script>
<script>
var isClicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        isClicked = true;
    });
    if (isClicked == true)
    {
        $('#test').animate({top:'200px'});
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The animation is not playing... obviously the same task could be accomplished in an easier way, but I still don't understand why the variable is not working.  Probably just a stupid typo - but maybe not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to put the code with the if condition inside the click handler....? By the way what are you trying to achieve with the isClicked flag? `$('#test').click(function(){
        if (isClicked)
       {
            $(this).animate({top:'200px'});
       } isClicked = !isClicked; 
    });`

Comment: At the time of evaluating if `isClicked` (`==true`), `isClicked` isn't set. The code doesn't know it yet.

Comment: When you click, you just set the variable `isClicked` to `true` and nothing else. Put that `if (...) {...}` inside the function of the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the DOM is loaded, isClicked will have the value 'false'. Since the value is false, the animation will not occur. Change your JS in something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isClicked = false;
    $('#test').on('click', function (event) {
        isClicked = !isClicked;
        if (isClicked) {
            $(this).animate({top: '200px'});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your test of `isClicked` is performed at dom ready, and at that point, you haven't clicked yet.

You should move the code in the click handler function.